# Why else block is executed if num1, num2, and 0 at the end is assigned to if block?

Tags: c, if-statement, variable-assignment

In this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i;

    if(i= 50,40)
        printf(" if blk i %d\n",i);
    else
        printf(" else part" );



    return 0;
}
```

the output comes as

> if blk i 50

but when a zero is added to the assignment part in if statement, it goes to the else part. Why is this 0 making it go to else part?

the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i;

    if(i= 50,40,0)
        printf(" if blk i %d\n",i);
    else
        printf(" else blk i %d\n", i);

    printf("i %d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What in the world do you think `i= 50,40` does? Search about the comma operator and the assignment operator. Also C and C++ are different languages! Don't add wrong tags!

Comment: @olaf well thanks for the comma operator thing, but apart from that , for this small code piece both c and c++ work same, i just checked it. Sorry for the bad post anyways

Comment: Not if you overload one of the operators. Identical syntax&grammar does not imply identical semantics! Just pick the language you use.

Comment: Programming by guessing does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this statement:

```
if(i= 50,40)
```

is actually a:

```
if(40)
```

comma operator causes first `i` to be assigned to 50 (comma operator has lower precedence than assignment), then as a condition a last element is used which is `40`

> but when a zero is added to the assignment part in if statement, it goes to the else part.

becasue then as a condition a last element is used which is `0`. `0` causes `if` to fail, and execute else block.

Answer (score 3):

You're making use of the **comma operator**.  The value of an expression using this operator is the value of the right side.

In this case:

```
(i= 50,40)
```

`i` is first set to 50, then the value 40 is evaluated, so the expression has the value 40.  Because this is a non-zero value, it evaluates to true in a boolean context and enters the `if` part.

In this case:

```
(i= 50,40,0)
```

The same as above happens, but then 0 is evaluated, so the expression has the value 0.  Zero evaluates to false in a boolean context so it enters the `else` part.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `a, b` first evaluates `a` and throws away the result.
Then it evaluates `b`, and that value is the result of the expression.

`i= 50,40` first evaluates `i = 50` and then produces `40` as its result.
Since `40` is not `0`, it is converted to `true` for the conditional.

`i = 50, 40, 0` evaluates `i = 50`, then `40`, then `0`, which becomes the value of the expression.
And `0` converts to `false`.

`i = (50,40)`, on the other hand, would assign `40` to `i` and ignore the `50` completely.